# Which is the loadrunner protocol to record the desktop application?

Tags: desktop-application, loadrunner

Is there any protocol in load runner to record and play a desktop application? Im using load runner (micro focus) version 2021.

Comment: What is the next upstream architectural component that your application communicates with?   LoadRunner supports some 20++ different interfaces plus the ability to use application source code directly, or go upstream with GUI, Citrix or RDP virtual users

Answer (score 0):

You should select the `Web-HTTP/HTML` protocol and in record window you need to select `Windows application`. Remember you need to provide the desktop `.exe` file location.

**Example**: *`C:\Program Files (x86)\Teams Installer\Teams.exe`*

Please see the below steps for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Im looking for something like image capturing and then playing the recorded script just like a sikuli tool do.

Comment: The above answer ~~~~~assumes~~~~~ an application "speaks" HTTP.  That assumption may or may not be correct depending upon the application tested